# TCropping images with loop in imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick

A pretty basic question but I'm new to 
Imagemagick (and bash) and I'm having trouble batch cropping images in a folder. I've tried using a loop:

```
for image in '/home/donald/Desktop/New Folder'*.jpg; do 
    convert "$image" -gravity center -crop 95X95% "${image%.jpg}"-modified.jpg
done
```

but it returns:

```
convert.im6: unable to open image `/home/donald/Desktop/New Folder/*.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: no images defined `/home/donald/Desktop/New Folder/*-modified.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044."
```

What would be the proper way of doing this?

Edit: Apparently a space in the folder name was causing problems I deleted it and things seem to be working.Apparently if you want to use a folder with a space name in bash you need to escape the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have no `jpg` files in the `/home/donald/Desktop/New Folder/` directory. The shell will interpret it as the literal string `/home/donald/Desktop/New Folder/*.jpg` if there are no files matching the wildcard-ed string.

See this example:

```
$ for f in *.jpg*; do echo $f; done
file.jpg
file2.jpg
$ for f in *.jpgg; do echo $f; done
*.jpgg
```

See how that last one is the literal string and not a real file? It should have been displayed the first time too if it was (notice the trailing asterix symbol in `*.jpg*`).

You can fix this by checking if the file exists before executing the command, using `[ -f "${file}" ]`. For instance:

```
for image in '/home/donald/Desktop/New Folder'*.jpg; do 
    [ -f "${image}" ] && convert "$image" -gravity center -crop 95X95% "${image%.jpg}"-modified.jpg
done
```

This will check if the file `image` exists (`-f`) and execute the following statement only if true is returned `&&`. Had you written `||` instead of `&&` then the following statement would be executed when false was returned.

Note that bash doesn't return true or false but it's the easiest way to explain and comprehend the notation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did have a jpg in the folder but you're right that it didn't recognize it as existing. I just barely tried to cd into the folder and it didn't work, so I tried deleting the space in the folder name and for some reason things are working fine now.

Comment: Okay, nice to hear! Don't forget to accept if the answer worked for you and/or upvote if you deemed it a quality answer. If your solution was not inspired by this answer: post your answer and accept it. You are allowed to do that, just so the next person who runs into this issue can more easily find a solution to his/her problem. Questions with solutions but no accepted answers are not good for the community!